# Why is the hidden attribute not working on the picture element in next.js?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I have a picture element in my component tree in a **Next.js** application and I am trying to use the hidden attribute on it, but it doesn't work, all the images are still completely visible and there's no hidden attribute when inspecting them in the browser.

The component is:

```
export function MemberPicture({
  member,
  active,
  id,
}: {
  member: Member;
  active: boolean;
  id: string;
}) {  

  return (
    <picture hidden={!active}>
      <source srcSet={member.images.webp} type="image/webp" />
      <Image
        src={member.images.png}
        alt={member.imageAlt}
        width="445"
        height="445"
        id={id}
        className={classnames(
          pageStyles.image,
        )}
      />
    </picture>
  );
}
```

I've tried to set the hidden attribute on all the elements inside the picture and on the picture itself using a literal boolean value of `true`, but it doesn't work either.

```
<picture hidden={true}>
      <source srcSet={member.images.webp} type="image/webp" hidden={true} />
      <Image
        src={member.images.png}
        alt={member.imageAlt}
        width="445"
        height="445"
        id={id}
        className={classnames(
          pageStyles.image,
        )}
        hidden={true}
      />
    </picture>
```

The component is being used as shown:

```
{crew.map((member, index) => {
  return (
    <MemberPicture
      id={imagesIds[index]}
      active={index === selectedMemberIndex}
      member={member}
    />
  );
})}
```

Its parent's styles and its styles are:

```
.imageWrapper {
  grid-area: image;
  max-width: 100%;
}

@media (min-width: 50em) and (orientation: landscape) {
  .imageWrapper {
    grid-column: span 2;
    max-width: 90%;
  }
}

.image {
  max-width: 100%;
}

@media (max-width: 35em) {
  .image {
    max-height: 320px;
  }
}
```

I am going to use the `display` property set to `none` as the hidden attribute is not working, but I still would like to know why setting that attribute does not work at all.

Comment: Can you make a codesandbox reproducing the issue? `<picture hidden>` works fine for me.

Comment: Check this out [The `hidden` Attribute is Visibly Weak](https://css-tricks.com/the-hidden-attribute-is-visibly-weak/)

Comment: @SlavaKnyazev I found the solution. It was just that there was a `display: block;` property overriding the `hidden` attribute somewhere in my CSS and the `hidden` attribute actually did appear on the element when i inspected it in the browser, I just didn't look at it carefully